# Error in UseMethod(“cld”) : no applicable method for 'cld' applied to an object of class “c('emm_list', 'list')”

Tags: r

Try to run the cld function to show me the significant differences, but it doesn´t work.

At the end the program is showing -> Error in UseMethod(“cld”) : no applicable method for 'cld' applied to an object of class “c('emm_list', 'list')”

All necessary packages are installed.. Can anybody help me?

```
library(emmeans)
library(lattice)
library(pbkrtest)
library(car)
library(agricolae)
library(agriTutorial)
library(multcompView)
library(car)

View(WG)
attach(WG)
names(WG)
WG$PGPM <- as.factor(WG$PGPM)
WG$Düngung<- as.factor(WG$Düngung)
WG$WDH<-as.factor(WG$WDH)
WG$Variante<-as.factor(WG$Variante)
WG$Parzelle<-as.factor(WG$Parzelle)

mais.lmer=lmer(Kornertrag~WDH+PGPM*Düngung+(1|WDH:PGPM),data=WG)
anova(mais.lmer,ddf="Kenward-Roger")

shapiro.test(resid(mais.lmer))
leveneTest(Kornertrag~PGPM*Düngung, data=WG)

emmeans::contrast(emmeans::emmeans(mais.lmer,~PGPM|Düngung), alpha=0.05, method="pairwise")
cld(emmeans(mais.lmer, specs = "PGPM", by = "Düngung", contr = "pairwise"))
cld(emmeans(mais.lmer, specs = "Düngung", by = "PGPM", contr = "pairwise"), Letters=letters, reversed=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Omit the `contr` argument, because it creates its own contrasts.  And use `multcomp::cld()` because the generic is in the multcomp package.

Comment: You are my Hero! Thank you very much, it works!

Comment: Glad it works. But consider NOT using CLDs. They are misleading because they display NON-findings rather than findings